# 2.7 Developer Log Error submit_entry() to shannel_form_submit_entry_end

Tags: 2.7.0

Getting a Developer log error when I edit an entry using the channel:form.

Deprecated function submit_entry() called in system/expressionengine/modules/channel/mod.channel.php on line 5291.
Deprecated since 2.7. Use Renamed to: channel_form_submit_entry_end instead.

When I create an entry - all is fine, it is only editing that I'm getting a call to a developer log error.

Any ideas? I've checked to see the modules using submit_entry and after searching, nothing is showing.

Answer (score 1):

first thing check that all your addons is updated to last version.

go to your database table Tools > Data > Sql manger > mange database tables  and check exp_extensions table to see if any extension used safecracker_submit_entry_XX hooks , if there any check their names and update them to last version.

check it and let me know.

Regard's.

Comment: Aha! Its CE Cache. I believe I have the most recent version. They said they updated their module to not have this error so i'll check back. Good call on the SQL manager!Thanks:)